# Lockout time for Ethereum accounts

Tags: accounts, password

What is the default lockout time for Ethereum accounts? 
I know that we can mention the time until which we need the account in unlocked state:

```
personal.unlockAccount(addr, pswd, duration)
```

This command will keep the account unlocked for the specified duration (seconds).

But, if I don't mention the time and unlock an account like this:

```
personal.UnlockAccount(addr, pswd)
```

After how much time will it be locked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal_unlockaccount):

> The unencrypted key will be held in memory until the unlock duration
>   expires. If the unlock duration defaults to **300 seconds**. An explicit
>   duration of zero seconds unlocks the key until geth exits.

**Edit:**

Note that there appears to be a stray "if" in there. The second sentence should read "The unlock duration defaults to "300 seconds".

Comment: If the unlock duration defaults to `300 seconds.` --> I don't understand. Are we supposed to configure this somewhere?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like there's a stray "if" in there. It should just read: "The unlock duration defaults to 300 seconds."

Comment: Also, what does the second sentence mean? `An explicit duration of zero seconds unlocks the key until geth exits.`

Comment: That means if you put `0` as the third argument, then it will stay unlocked until the programme ends. i.e. It prevents the default 300 seconds from kicking in.